# How to pass iterable React.Component to react-i18next Trans component?

Tags: react-i18next

I'm trying to pass several components, that created by map function, to translation component **Trans**.
In previous versions I was able to use anything as a variable, but with new API of react-i18next it seems not so easy.
For now I cannot add list of items to translation, because it renders as `[object Object]`. Yeah, it is `React.Node`, and I cannot use it as `values`, but as a simple component it renders only the first component (in my case `ul`)

#### Sample to demonstrate my headache:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ojqxzpw86y

Maybe somebody could help, or suggest something.
No, I don't want to remove list from translations =(

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? You can translate components one by one, not in a loop.

Comment: i have list of dynamic data and want to it pass in the translation. Actually, I've found how to do this - just create React.Element.